# Снедь = пища, еда. А можно ли готовить снедь?

Tags: лексика

> Китайцы умеют оптимизировать свой бизнес – свою снедь они готовят из
>   местных продуктов, оттого характерного вкуса у кухни не будет.

"Вкус у кухни" - ничего?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)
Снедь - пища, ее можно выпекать, нарезать, готовить и т. п. Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Она много лет преподавала этот предмет в профтехучилище, теперь помимо руководства Домом творчества ведёт клуб "Хозяюшка", где будущие мамы и бабушки учатся **выпекать** пироги, кулебяки, блины и прочую вкусную домашнюю **снедь**, притягивающую в дом и хозяев, и гостей. [Роща из... теста // «Народное творчество», 2003]

Опрятная женщина средних лет в переднике **нарезала** к обеду какую-то **снедь**. [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]

Когда же сообразно приготовленную необыкновенную **снедь** потом **нарезали**, с ее доисторических боков открашивалась наиболее вкусная плоть. [Асар Эппель. Чреватая идея // «Знамя», 2002]  [омонимия не снята

Главная особенность сельской кухни заключается в том, что **снедь** **готовишь** на всем своем. [Вячеслав Пьецух. Письма из деревни // «Октябрь», 2001]

(2)
Кухня - подбор кушаний. Французская, китайская, итальянская, русская к.

А в вашей фразе очевидно имелось в виду, что приготовленная снедь не будет иметь вкуса, характерного для китайской кухни.

**Китайцы умеют оптимизировать свой бизнес – свою снедь они готовят из местных продуктов, оттого характерного (для китайской кухни) вкуса не будет.**

а еще точнее:

**Китайцы умеют оптимизировать свой бизнес – свою снедь они готовят из местных продуктов, оттого характерного (для китайской кухни) вкуса у нее нет.**

Comment: По поводу 2. Вопрос не "что такое кухня", а возможен ли (и этот ли) предлог: *вкус У кухни*.

Comment: По смыслу у вас идет речь о вкусе снеди, а не о вкусе кухни. Автор путает эти понятия. Что такое кухня см. выше.

Comment: Можно ли сказать: "У китайской кухни особый вкус"? Думаю, да.

Comment: В данном смысле китайская кухня = еда, проготовленная по китайским рецептам.

Answer (score 2):

"Вкус у кухни" - плохо, @М_Г подробно и доступно изложила "почему". А если отойти только от лексики и дойти до логики, то с кухнями *больших* сообществ (а китайское - большое) получится, что некий единый "вкус" - скорее миф, чем реальность.

Фраза корявая, смешение стилей и слегка издевательство над логикой. "Вкус у кухни" - в любом случае в отброс